# How can save data using cloud functions to firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I saw some other answers and I tried some of those unsuccessfully.

In my case, I created an iOS app and integrated Stripe payment method, so it reaches my javascript function at cloud functions. I'm actually able to see the payments I realizes within my stripe account but I couldn't manage to save it into our firestore database.

this is my setup at Google side:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token); 
//I've preset this data to firebase functions middleware

    function charge(req, res) {
        const body = (req.body);

        const userId = body.userId;
        const token = body.token;
        const amount = body.amount;
        const currency = body.currency;

        // Charge card
        stripe.charges.create({
            amount,
            currency,
            description: 'Firebase Example',
            source: token,
        }).then(charge => {
            send(res, 200, {
    // I WANNA RECORD DATA INTO MY DATABASE HERE!!
                message: 'Success',
                charge,
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            send(res, 500, {
                error: err.message,
            });
        });
    }

    function send(res, code, body) {
        res.send({
            statusCode: code,
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        });
    }

    app.use(cors);
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {

        // Catch any unexpected errors to prevent crashing
        try {
            charge(req, res);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            send(res, 500, {
                error: `The server received an unexpected error. Please 
try again and contact the site admin if the error persists.`,
            });
        }
    });

exports.charge = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And this is our database setup where I want to save like this: 
- into payments > userId... I'll save each transaction this userId does with the fields: "token", "currency" and "amount".

Note: I already have all this values in my function and also have userId.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT8OY.png)

Comment: Hey I see you're using Stripe within your cloud functions and wanted to share this tutorial: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-stripe-payments-part-2-firebase-cloud-functions-backend/ . This is a great start for handling the payment coordination with firestore. It also has helpers showing storing data in firestore utilizing the admin API for firebase.

Comment: Nicholas Pesa, Thank you for the hint. i'll give a look here.